# Philippines visa on arrival with Singapore eVisa

Tags: tourist-visas, singapore, philippines

I am a citizen of India. I have a Singapore 35-day multiple-entry visa. Am I eligible to get a visa on arrival in the Philippines, without going to Singapore on this visa?

Is it mandatory to go to Singapore on this eVisa once to get a visa on arrival in the Philippines?

I've never been to Singapore or Philippines before.

I have a confirmed return ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for writing the answer late. That year I was successfully able to go to the Philippines (an amazing country and great people).

However, I was questioned for longer than normal on both the Airports departure (India) and arrival (PH).

I was asked why are you doing this - so I showed them the visa application that I prepared, for the Philippines visa request, and explained that they have 45 days window - meaning travelers must have a flight scheduled within 45 days after applying for a visa. This timeline was way shorter for me, I wanted the visa within 15 days.

I also showed them the official document which says that any person who has an SG visa can easily get a PH visa on arrival.

They checked my bags and then let me enter the country.

I would say this is not the right way to travel it is risky and not ethical, but I was desperate and it was a career turning point for me. So I had no choice but to go via SG visa

Comment: *not ethical*? What?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I am not exactly getting what are you asking, but maybe you meant that it is fine if we take SG visa and go to PH believe me PH security didn't like it, but when I explained they agreed as an exception. They have the full right to say no.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella It's not particularly "nice" towards Singapore to get their visa for the sole purpose of visiting the Philippines, but then again, the OP paid for the privilege, so it doesn't seem hugely unethical to me.

Answer (score 5):

According to Timatic, the tool used by airlines to check document requirements ([courtesy of Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&h=afa33a9a7c5827aea2dcdb136913fee6ffd911d)), you do not need a visa to enter the Philippines. Note that having the visa by Singapore exempts you, with no other conditions such as its use.

> **[Philippines (PH)](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&h=afa33a9a7c5827aea2dcdb136913fee6ffd911d)**
>
> **Visa Exemptions:** 
>   Nationals of India traveling as a tourist with a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months beyond the period of intended stay, for a maximum stay of 14 days. They must have a valid tourist, business or resident visa issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Singapore, USA, United Kingdom, or a Schengen Member State .
>
> **Additional Information:**
>   Length of stay is calculated by starting on the next day after the day of arrival in the Philippines.
>
> Extension of stay possible for an additional 7 days, for nationals of India entering the Philippines when holding a valid tourist, business or resident visa or permanent residence permit issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Singapore, USA, United Kingdom, or a Schengen Member State .

Comment: Hey, could you also please add the source link? Why did you mention Republic of Korea is their a connection?

Comment: It was in the Emirates link; I've added it to the content, at [Philippines](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&h=afa33a9a7c5827aea2dcdb136913fee6ffd911d)