# Visa on Arrival Procedure & Documentation at Manila Airport

Tags: visas, philippines, visas-on-arrival, manila

I understand that if I have a Singapore visa (with an Indian passport) I do not need to apply for a Philippines visa. But upon arrival in Manila, will I need to apply for a Visa on Arrival at the airport? Or will I just be able to go directly to Immigration and pass through without a visa? If it is a visa on arrival, what documents are required and what is the cost?

Comment: @CGCampbell I can remember of a question of one that states that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Philippines visa on arrival with Singapore eVisa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120523/philippines-visa-on-arrival-with-singapore-evisa)

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120523/philippines-visa-on-arrival-with-singapore-evisa ... yes, there are multiple posts and websites confirming this. Plus my travel agent has assured me that many of his clients have visited Philippines on an Indian passport with only a Singapore visa.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120523/philippines-visa-on-arrival-with-singapore-evisa ... this doesn't answer my question. I know that I can go on a Singapore visa. My question is about the process upon arrival. How long will it take? Is there a separate counter that I need to visit? Is there a separate fee?

Comment: @VipulSwarup OK, but now I question why you are asking us, when you state you use a travel agent. They are professionals, we are Random Internet Strangers.

Comment: @VipulSwarup What has your own research on the topic revealed?

Comment: Nothing useful yet. I am going in 4 days' time. I will write an update here, after experiencing it first-hand.

Answer (score 2):

so I am in the Philippines now. Below is my experience from Immigration at Manila airport.

I went straight to Immigration - there was no separate visa-on-arrival counter. The waiting time at immigration was longer than 1 hour though — very poorly managed queues, and slow moving officers.

The officer looked at the following:

- Philippines e-travel pass (its a QR code covid check thing). You can get one here: https://etravel.gov.ph/. My travel agent did not know about this, and luckily the airline made me register before checking me in.
- Passports - obviously
- Singapore Visa
- Return ticket
- And, rather weirdly, proof that our daughter is indeed our daughter. Our Indian passports have parents’ names endorsed in passports - so this was not an issue. But I have never been asked this before.

They did not ask for hotel bookings, photographs, or any kind of payment.

Comment: Glad to hear it all went well, and thanks for taking the time to come back and post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

> And, rather weirdly, proof that our daughter is indeed our daughter.
> Our Indian passports have parents’ names endorsed in passports - so
> this was not an issue. But I have never been asked this before.

LOT of child trafficking incidents hence they need to ensure this. Ideally they ask for birth certificate.